# cannot add foreign key constraint error 1215 phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database

Currently working with a database in `phpmyadmin` and I'm trying to set up a foreign key constraint.
Parent Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productcategory` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  `categoryManager` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `emailAddress` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `managerPhoneNum` tinyint(10) NOT NULL,
  `managerDateAppointed` date NOT NULL,
  `managerLocation` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `productcategory` (`ID`, `Name`, `Description`, `categoryManager`, `emailAddress`, `managerPhoneNum`, `managerDateAppointed`, `managerLocation`) VALUES
(2, 'General Fiction', 'General Fiction from all aspects, you''ll find authors such as, George RR Martin, Cormac McCarthy and so forth ', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00', ''),
(4, '', '', '', '', 0, '0000-00-00', ''),
(5, '', '', 'localhost', '2016-01-21', 0, '0000-00-00', 'Crumlin'),
(6, '', '', 'Test', '2016-02-18', 0, '0000-00-00', 'Dun Laoighre'),
(7, '', '', 'hchchcvh', '2016-02-11', 0, '0000-00-00', 'Gorey'),
(8, '', '', 'localhost', '', 0, '0000-00-00', '');


ALTER TABLE `productcategory`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `ID` (`ID`);


ALTER TABLE `productcategory`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

Child table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AuthorName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `BookName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `CostPrice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sellPrice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCatID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `product` (`ProductID`, `AuthorName`, `BookName`, `CostPrice`, `sellPrice`, `productCatID`) VALUES
(4, 'Cormac McCarthy', 'The Road', 9, 11, 2),
(9, 'J.R Tolkein', 'The Two Towers', 3, 6, 2);


ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`),
  ADD KEY `productCatID` (`productCatID`);



ALTER TABLE `product`
  MODIFY `ProductID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=12;
```

And here is the query I'm running to add the constraint:

```
`ALTER TABLE `product` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`productCatID`)
 REFERENCES `highland_books_database`.`productcategory`(`ID`) ON DELETE          RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;`
```

I have indexed the primary key of each tables. I have made sure they are both using InnoDB and I have set up the correct relational view for each table but when I go to add a foreign key constraint on the productCat ID row in the product table I keep getting this error message. I've tried reading the documentation but cant find what my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):
>
> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. **The size and sign of integer types must be the same.** The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

You need to have the same datatype:

```
productcategory => `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
```

vs.

```
product => `productCatID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
```

Remove `unsigned` from column definition.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92d1a/3/0)**</kbd>